# Clone a repository from a VSTS account to a different TFS account and peform pulls for update

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

I have struggling with something which I don't know if it is possible.

I want to be able to clone a repository from a VSTS account to a different TFS account.

Then, I want the second TFS account to perform pull operations regularly to update the repository according to the one in the first VSTS account.

I tried to use "Import repository" from Microsoft but haven't been working. Plus, this has to be done manually. Is there a way to import a repository only once from once from one TFS project to another different TFS and set it to perform regular pull operations?

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/import-git-repository]
[image: Error when importing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no automated system in place to setup syncs between repositories on different Accounts or TFS servers.

But if you consider that a sync on a trigger is very similar to a scheduled build or a CI build, it's actually not that hard to create a build definition that performs a git pull of all branches and all tags, adds the other remote and then immediately afterwards performs a git push to push those same elements to another account.

I'm not aware of a custom task in the marketplace that does this, so you'll have to script it out manually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer about automation. About importing a repository from a TFS account to another, do you know what is the procedure? I used the "clone" URL, provided the correct authorization and tried to import using the tool from the screenshot from the second TFS trying to clone the repository from the first.

Comment: You need to create Alternate Credentials I suppose. Cross Server Windows Auth isn't something that is supported as far as I know (but I'm not 100% sure).

Comment: Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Clone a repo from VSTS to TFS (or across two TFS accounts) is possible.

But there is no such settings to pull the changes from the original repo to the imported repo since there are already two different repos. If you want to sync the two repos, you should use scripts or the auto triggered CI build (as jessehouwing said).

To answering the way to import repo from VSTS to TFS and across two TFS account, you can refer the authorization of importing a git repo as below:

- Import git repo from VSTS to TFS

  For the requires authorization, the email address and the password to login your VSTS account can not be used, you should **use PAT or Alternate credential**.
- Import git repo across two TFS account

  Import a git repo from the first TFS account to second TFS account, you should **input the fully username (`domain\name`) for the first TFS account authorization**. Such as the username like `fareast\myname`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to import using PAT or alternate credential. I can do that from the VSTS account to another VSTS account without problems, by using PAT and credentials. However, neither PAT or credentials works when importing from VSTS to my TFS. The TFS address starts with "http://teamfoundation:8080/tfs/main/", which is a local TFS on premise with no direct access to the internet. Perhaps that is the problem...